# how to pass parameter from @Url.Action to controller function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a function `CreatePerson(int id)` , I want to pass `id` from `@Url.Action`.

Below is the reference code:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(int id) //controller 
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person") + id";
```

the above code fails to pass `id` value to `CreatePerson` function.

Answer (score 127):

you can pass it this way :

```
Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = id }));
```

OR can also pass this way

```
Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { id = id });
```

Comment: What if the code is inside javascript? `window.refresh({url: '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { id = Id })',` -> this code breaks because I can't pass a variable in there. It only works if hardcoded: `@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { id = "someId" })',` -> How to make this work?

Comment: I'm looking for this answer too

Comment: If a function is in a javascript file what you can do is put the url on the view in a hidden field and then call it using javascript. eg:

<input id="url">@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { id = Id })<\input>

Then call it in javascript: $("#url").val();

Comment: Here's what I do: var url = '@Url.Action("Foo","Bar", new {id="replaceToken"})'; Then url = url.replace("replaceToken", yourID);

Comment: @chiapa I know I'm replying to a long dead comment, but anyway, it's easier to pass these as parameters separately instead of a entire Razor command, as in `new { action = "CreatePerson", controller = "Person", id = Id }`, then in your Action redirect to the action received as a parameter with `RedirectToAction(action, controller, id)`

Answer (score 28):

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson (string id)

window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person" , new {id = "ID"})'.replace("ID",id);

public ActionResult CreatePerson (int id)

window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person" , new {id = "ID"})'.replace("ID", parseInt(id));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(int id) //controller 

window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person")?id=' + id;
```

Or

```
var id = 'some value';
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new {id = id})';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(int id) //controller 

window.location.href = "@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person")?Id='+Id+'";
```

it's working fine passing parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Need To Two Or More Parameters Passing Throw view To Controller Use This Syntax...
Try.. It.

```
var id=0,Num=254;var str='Sample';    
var Url = '@Url.Action("ViewNameAtController", "Controller", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id= "id", Num= "Num", Str= "str" }))'.replace("id", encodeURIComponent(id));
    Url = Url.replace("Num", encodeURIComponent(Num));
    Url = Url.replace("Str", encodeURIComponent(str));
    Url = Url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
window.location.href = Url;
```

Answer (score 2):

This way to pass value from Controller to View:

```
ViewData["ID"] = _obj.ID;
```

Here is the way to pass value from View to Controller back:

```
<input type="button" title="Next" value="Next Step" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { ID = ViewData["ID"] })'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(string Enc)

 window.location = '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person", new { Enc = "id", actionType = "Disable" })'.replace("id", id).replace("&amp;", "&");
```

you will get the id inside the Enc string.

Comment: Thanks It's Working.... .replace("id", encodeURIComponent(id)) This is also Reqired.....

Answer (score 0):

should you pass it in this way :

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(int id) //controller 
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person",new { @id = 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Url.Action("Survey", "Applications", new { applicationid = @Model.ApplicationID }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Url.Action` inside JavaScript then you can

```js
var personId="someId";
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '@Url.Action("CreatePerson", "Person")',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: ({
  //insert your parameters to pass to controller
    id: personId 
  }),
  success: function() {
    alert("Successfully posted!");
  }
});
```