# Passing parameter to @Url.Action

Tags: parameter-passing, url.action

I am trying to pass two parameters through a @Url.Action for a submit button. However, the values are not being passed.

I have index view with a dropdown field and a Save button. What I would like for the user to be able to do is select a dropdown value and Save the value. However, no matter how I access my function the values are null. I have tried passing in parameters and binding the data.

Currently my view looks like -

```
<h3>Burn Conditions</h3>
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConditionsReasonsID, "Condition", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ConditionsReasonsID", String.Empty)
        @ViewBag.conditionsReasons
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConditionsReasonsID)
        <a href= "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("CreateCondition", "RequestedBurns", new { requestedBurnsID = ViewBag.RequestedBurnsID, conditionsReasonsID = Model.ConditionsReasonsID }))"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Save Condition"  />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my controller I have

```
public ActionResult CreateCondition(int requestedBurnsID, int conditionsReasonsID)
    {
        BurnDecision burnDecision = new BurnDecision();
        burnDecision.RequestedBurnsID = requestedBurnsID;
        burnDecision.ConditionsReasonsID = conditionsReasonsID;

        //Find BurnSiteID
        RequestedBurn requestedBurn = db.RequestedBurns.Find(burnDecision.RequestedBurnsID);
        ViewBag.burnSitesID = requestedBurn.BurnSitesID;
        db.BurnDecisions.Add(burnDecision);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "RequestedBurns", new { burnSitesID = ViewBag.burnSitesID, requestedBurnsID = burnDecision.RequestedBurnsID });

    }
```

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017513/how-to-pass-parameter-from-url-action-to-controller-function-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: I tried passing the parameter as `conditionsReasonsID = @Model.ConditionsReasonsID` and `conditionsReasonsID = ViewData["ConditionsReasonsID"]` and it is still `null`.