# Passing model from view to controller with additional string

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to pass model to my Action in Controller and i need to pass string too.

Something like that:

```
<a class="btn" title="Send" href="@Url.Action("Check","Approve",Model && new{redirectTo = "ShowPDF")">Send</a>
```

Is any way to do that?(For me better way) Or must I add value to Model.Redirect "OnClick" and how to do that? (Not wanted way)

My solution:

```
<a class="btn" title="Send" href="@Url.Action("Check","Approve",new { ID =Model.ID,EAN =Model.ID_EAN, ic = Model.invoiceNumber, s = Model.supplier, a = Model.amount, d = Model.dueDate, redirect = "ShowPDF"  })">Send</a>
```

I did it this way, but for me this way is very complicated on model change.

Check Action:

```
public ActionResult Check(string ic, string s, decimal a, DateTime d, int ID, string EAN, string redirect = "Index")
        {
            ...
            return RedirectToAction(redirect);

        }
```

Comment: how does your `Check` action method looks like ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass parameter from @Url.Action to controller function in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017513/how-to-pass-parameter-from-url-action-to-controller-function-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send only few properties of your Model, it is fine to  follow your  solution. But if you want to send a whole lot of properties of a model,  keep in mind that there is a limit for how much data querystrings are allowed to carry ( varied by browsers).

Instead you should send the data in in the form. If you want to send some data via a form, it should be a form element. You can create an input elemenet or a hidden input element

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("check","approve"))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(p=>p.ID_EAN)
  @Html.HiddenFor(p=>p.ID)
  <!-- Add a hidden element for other properties you want to send -->
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="ShowPDF" />
  <inpu type="submit" />
}
```

And you can use the same view model as the param of your HttpPost action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Check(YourModel model,string redirect)
{
  // to do : Return something
}
```

**But......**,

if you are not changing any values in the view, You do not need to send the entire form. Simply send the unique Id value of the entity(primary key) and in the HttpPost action method, using that unique Id, get the full entity (query the database) and use that. Remember, you should never trust the value coming from the client(browser). For this, you can use your solution, you do not need form as you are sending only 2 values.