# Dotnet Core button redirect with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core

I'm making a Web API application that populates data into a datagrid. Currently, I'm wanting to have a button that will call my webapi endpoint with an additional parameter.

My datagrid, and the button code is below. This is the entirety of my razor page code:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Batch>().ID("gridContainer")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add().CellTemplate(
        @<text>
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
              .ID("sendButton")
              .Text("Select Batch")
            .OnClick("function () { onItemClick(data); }"))
        </text>);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.BatchId).Caption("BatchId");
        columns.AddFor(m => m.CobId).Caption("Cob Id");                                                                        
        })                                                                                                            
        .DataSource(d => d.WebApi().Controller("Batches").LoadAction("GetAllEntries").Key("BatchId"))
)



<script>  

    var idValue;
    function onItemClick(data)
    {          
        DevExpress.ui.notify(data.Id);
        console.log(data.BatchId);

        idValue = data.BatchId;

         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SeanTest", "BatchDatagrid", new {@id = idValue })';
    }

</script>
```

In my script the variable `idValue` contains the value I want to pass into my URL, yet when I try to place it in the Url.Action it tells me that `it doesn't exist in the current context`

What is the best way to pass `idValue` into my redirect action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass parameter from @Url.Action to controller function in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017513/how-to-pass-parameter-from-url-action-to-controller-function-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Url.Action is processed at the server side. So passing a dynamic value from client side to it may not be possible. But as a work-around you can use the below code

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SeanTest", "BatchDatagrid", new {@id = "ID"})'.replace("ID",idValue );
```

If you like it, credit should be given to the original poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33371488/1363011)