# Parameters in ASP.NET MVC to create a PDF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a particular problem, I am working with ASP.NET MVC in C# and SQL Server. The idea is that on the main screen you see a text box and a button, entering a number that brings us our data. By bringing that data, the person can choose whether they want to see if that data in a PDF. But, when I try to carry out those data to the pdf the problem arises that I will show.

**Index:**

```
<div>
        <form method="post" action="/Home/ChRoja">
            <p>Titulo: <input type="text" name="titulo" /></p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Chequera Roja" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }

   public ActionResult ChRoja() 
   {
       ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
       double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["titulo"].ToString());
       return View(cn.cargarDatos(titulo));
   }

   public ActionResult Pdf()
   {
       double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["id"].ToString());
       return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("ChRoja", titulo);
   }
```

ChRoja:

```
<body style='background: url(/images/CHEQUERAS-ROJAS-CORTA.png) no-repeat center'>
    <div>
        <form id="form">

            <div>
                <table back>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                            <td>

                                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "Pdf", new { id = item.Titulo })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>

        <a href="@Url.Action("Pdf", "Home")">Convertir a Pdf</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

So the problem is that when I press to view the PDF values ​​of the query the following happens:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass parameter from @Url.Action to controller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017513/how-to-pass-parameter-from-url-action-to-controller-function)

Comment: no, what i need is for the pdf to be created. But what I mentioned happens @SelimYıldız

Comment: It seems the problem is not about creating pdf. Obviously your problem is that you don't send `id` to server as a parameter. So `Request.Form["id"] `throws null exception.

Comment: You're not even getting to the PDF creation line. You need to solve the issue in the line that's actually failing. Then you can start looking at the PDF. BTW it's possible to do this on the client side.

Comment: Yes but how to send id as a parameter? I tried solve with the url how to you say me but not work to me @SelimYıldız

Comment: Pass what as a parameter? The entire page? The very first comment shows how you're meant to use parameters in MVC. First your view code needs to pass the value in the `@Url.Action` bit. Then your controller needs to accept it as a parameter. Please learn about passing parameters from views to controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong constructor for Html.ActionLink.
There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152575/pass-parameter-to-controller-from-html-actionlink-mvc-4).

Solution for your case is to add a parameter "Home" for the controller's action, as well as null at the end for htmlattributes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "Pdf", "Home", new { id = item.Titulo }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Change this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "Pdf", new { id = item.Titulo })
```

For this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "Pdf", new { titulo = item.Titulo })
```